# Did I do damage by replacing the rear rotors and pads with the parking brake engaged on a 2011 Mazda 3?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, parking-brake

I was helping my brother replace his rear brake pads and rotors on his 2011 Mazda 3. It was his first attempt at replacing brakes, and he didn't tell me he engaged his parking brake to prevent it from rolling (manual transmission). We successfully replaced both rear rotors and sets of pads, and we bled the lines for good measure. Getting the calipers off and depressing the caliper pistons was a real fight, but I didn't think to ask if he had put the e-brake on.

We haven't yet gone for a test drive because we need to replace the front rotors and pads tomorrow, so it's sitting in the garage. The emergency brake seems to be preventing the car from rolling at the moment, but it's on level ground.

Did we do damage by replacing the brakes with the parking brake on? If so, what is it likely we damaged? Is there anything we should test to be sure?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, we did no apparent damage to the rear brakes. The car has been driving fine for weeks on the replacement job.